# ¿porque los datos no se pasan bien atraves del socket cuando uso la ip pública?

Tags: c, windows, socket

Estoy haciendo un programa que usa sockets y el problema que tengo es que en un punto tiene que mandar un número pero cuando uso la ip pública para conectar el socket no lo recibe mientras que si uso la privada lo recibe perfectamente y esque no entiendo porque pasa eso.

En el codigo de abajo hay muchos `printf` que solo he puesto para ver donde fallaba

SERVIDOR

```
FILE *f;
    int i;
    int archivo=0;
    int carpeta=0;
    char necesario[200]="";
    char necesario1[200]="";
    char archivos[50][30];
    char carpetas[20][30];


    if(total==-1)
    {
        total=reconocimiento(nom);
        printf("aqui : %d\n\n",total);
        mandar_muilargo(sok,total);
        *hecho=total;
    }

    leer_carpetas(archivos,carpetas,nom,&carpeta,&archivo);

    printf("hay carpetas %d y  %d archivos\n",carpeta,archivo);

    send(sok,destino,strlen(destino)+1,0);

    printf("destino: %s\n",destino);

    mandar_datos(sok,&archivo,sizeof(archivo));

    printf("aa\n");
    printf("numero de archivos:%d\n",archivo);

    system("pause");
```

CLIENTE

```
char nombre[200];
    int i;
    int archivos;
    int carpetas;

    printf("aun no ha petado\n");

    if(longitud_carp==-1)
    {

    printf("aqui seguimos\n");

    if(recivir_muilargo(sok,&longitud_carp)==false)
    {
        printf("alto error compa\n");
        return false;
    }
    printf("\naa: %d\n",longitud_carp);
    printf("\naa: %d\n",*hecho);

    *hecho=longitud_carp;
    }

    recv(sok,nombre,sizeof(nombre),0);

    mkdir(nombre);
    printf("nombre de carpeta: %s\n",nombre);

    recivir_datos(sok,&archivos,sizeof(archivos));

    printf("numero de archivos: %d\n",archivos);

    printf("ya esta");
```

Leer_carepetas: Pasas el nombre de una carpeta y te dice el numero de archivos y carpetas que hay en ella así como los noombres de cada carpeta y cada archivo.

Reconocimiento: Hace la suma de todos los byts que hay en una carpeta y los guarda en un long long que viene en la funcion (por eso no lo he declarado).

Mandar_muilargo: Manda un long long usando htons

Mandar_datos: Manda cualquier tipo de datos.

Esto es lo que muestra la consola que es el problema:

SERVIDOR

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aqui a enviado los datos de la cantidad de byts que tiene la carpeta en y se supone que ya ha enviado el numero de archivos que hay

CLIENTE

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este ha recibido en numero de byts totales de la carpeta por lo que el firewall y la conexion están bien pero aunque el servidor se supone que ha mandado ya el numero el cliente no lo recibe y lo sigue esperando sinembargo si el socket es con la ip privada llega todo perfectamente.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! que quiere decir "no lo pasa bien"?? no llega? llega incompleto? tira un error?? por favor, usa el boton [edit] y explica exactamente que pasa...

Comment: @gbianchi no me da un error, directamente no llega y el cliente se queda esperando a que llegue.

Comment: Entonces, no lo pasa bien no es que no lo pasa. o el cliente no abre el puerto y no esta escuchando, o el servidor no logra enviar por ese puerto, o esta todo bloqueado por el firewall... Fijate que es muy diferente a no lo pasa bien. En lo posible, explica exactamente que pasa...

Comment: @gbianchi acabo de poner lo que muestra la consola. No es ni que lo bloquee el firawall ni que no esté escuchando el cliente por eso no se cual es el problema.

Comment: @gbianchi he resuelto el problema había que hacer que esperase el servidor unos 50 milisegundos hay alguna manera de arreglarlo de manera diferente. esque no se si ese tiempo cambiará según la velocidad de los ordenadores.

Comment: En general cuando hablas de comunicacion por puertos, son asincronicas.. eso quiere decir, que tu codigo deberia quedarse esperando a que exista una conexion, luego de eso a que termine de enviar los datos, etc... no hay tiempos, porque las redes no tienen tiempos estandar.. no se como esta todo eso en tu procesos... pero es lo que tenes que ir mirando...

Comment: La ip publica no es la ip de tu maquina, es la ip de una maquina de tu proveedor
de internet.